# "translate" multiple words from dictionary python

Tags: python, discord

So, I wrote this simple code:

```
szotar = {
    'lesz': 'lessz',
    'csalsz': 'csalo',
    'szia': 'helo'


}
```

(the message is given by user (on discord)

```
        msg = message.content.split(":")[1]
        ford = len(msg.split(" "))
        print(ford)
        for i in range(ford):
            done = msg.replace(msg.split(" ")[i], szotar[msg.split(" ")[i]])
        await message.channel.send(f"Leforditott: `{done}`", reference=message)
```

And it works fine with 1 word, but if it type more like: lesz szia csalsz, it only translates the last word. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You overwrite the variable `done` on each iteration and send the result of the last iteration

Comment: It's because you overwrite `done` each iteration of the loop.

Comment: how else can i do it?

Comment: You should be using the same variable while re-assigning the result of `.replace`, ie `msg = msg.replace`, and of course also use it when calling `send`

Comment: it is not working